# before_filter with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

I have a method that does something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_rights, :only => [:show]

def authenticate_rights
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to signin_path unless project.hidden
end
```

I also want to use this method in some other Controllers, so i copied the method to a helper that is included in the application_controller.

the problem is, that in some controllers, the id for the project isn't the `:id` symbol but f.e. `:project_id` (and also a `:id` is present (for another model)

How would you solve this problem? is there an option to add a parameter to the before_filter action (to pass the right param)?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
before_filter { |c| c.authenticate_rights correct_id_here }

def authenticate_rights(project_id)
  project = Project.find(project_id)
  redirect_to signin_path unless project.hidden
end
```

Where `correct_id_here` is the relevant id to access a `Project`.

Comment: is there a way to add a `,:only => [:show]` symbol? i'm getting an error trying `before_filter { |c| c.authenticate_rights correct_id_here }, :only => [:show]`

Comment: Try the other way around: `before_filter(:only => [:show]) { <block_code_here> }`. More examples here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

Comment: If you secure this by making the `before_filter` a private method, then perhaps re-factor (e.g. move it to a parent controller, ApplicationController, etc.), you'll need to use `c.send(:filter_name, ...)` as the filter will not run in the controller context.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters

Comment: Doing this makes it so the before_filter cannot be overridden/skipped due to it's lack of a name (proc). The values I want to pass in are class level. Is that possible?

Comment: How can I do this with a `:only` or a `:except` rule, like 
  `before_filter { |c| c.authenticate_admin! params[:id] }, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]` ?

Comment: The fact that passing the block requires using `send` means it's better to use a lambda as suggested in the answer of @vadym-tyemirov

Comment: FYI to beginners: `c` in this case is the controller, and you're calling an instance method you define in this controller.

Answer (score 67):

With some syntactic sugar:

```
before_filter -> { find_campaign params[:id] }, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Or if you decide to get even more fancy:

```
before_filter ->(param=params[:id]) { find_campaign param }, only: %i|show edit update destroy|
```

And since Rails 4 `before_action`, a synonym to `before_filter`, was introduced, so it can be written as:

```
before_action ->(param=params[:id]) { find_campaign param }, only: %i|show edit update destroy|
```

**NB**

`->` stands for `lambda`, called *lambda literal*, introduce in Ruby 1.9

`%i` will create an array of symbols

Comment: This answer is more elegant because the lambda defaults to the execution context of the class, hence private methods can be called without using '.send'

Comment: @Vadym Tyemirov Is `find_campaign` the private method name? In `param=params[:id]`, is `param` the name of the new local variable that will be passed as an argument to `find_campaign`? Meaning, that within the `find_campaign` private method itself, we use `param` not, `params{:id]`?

Comment: `find_campaign` could be either, but I'd make it private to be sure we don't expose what is not consumed. `params` is a hash variable available to our methods, `param` is any variable that you'd need to pass to find_campaign method, e.g. `before_action ->(campaign_id=params[:id]) { find_campaign(campaign_id) }, only: %i| show edit update destroy |`

Answer (score 14):

To continue @alex' answer, if you want to `:except` or `:only` some methods, here is the syntax:

```
before_filter :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy] do |c| c.authenticate_rights params[:id] end
```

Found [here](http://www.antunkarlovac.com/blog/2008/07/15/passing-arguments-to-before_filter-in-a-rails-controller/).

Answer (score 6):

I find the block method using curly braces instead of `do...end` to be the clearest option

```
before_action(only: [:show]) { authenticate_rights(id) }
```

`before_action` is just the newer preferred syntax for `before_filter`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
project = Project.find(params[:project_id] || params[:id])
```

This should return `params[:project_id]` if it is present in the params hash, or return `params[:id]` if it isn't.

Comment: the problem is, sometimes both are present (nested) and it finds a project that isn't the right one.

Comment: @choise: That should not happen: if `project_id` is present the `or` clause will ensure this is used - only if a `project_id` is not supplied will the `id` param be selected. In other words: when both parameters are supplied, the `or` clause ensures the correct value is used, as it will always prefer `project_id`. Naturally, you would not want to call this method when neither is present, or when there is no `project_id` but there is an `id` which does not reference a project.