# before_filter with parameters and private methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I want to pass some variables to a method called with the before_filter. It is possible to use the controller instance like [before_filter with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507026/before-filter-with-parameters). But in my case I have a private method.

I can't use the same solution for it.

Is there any way to parse the arguments to it?

Comment: There's a comment in the issue you linked that addresses this by using `.send` to invoke the private method.  Probably not the cleanest solution, but it works.  You could also set an instance variable and use that in your private method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not nice, as already was stated, but usage of `.send` does help and it is also mentioned in the [Action Controller Overview Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters), therefore I think there is no real better way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. :) Direct link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters