# syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end before_action :update_vote!(new_value)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am implementing a voting system for posts in my app. I am getting a syntax error that I am having difficult diagnosing.

This is a copy of the error in my rails server:

```
Started POST "/posts/44/up-vote" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-18 12:48:44 -0400

SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
    before_action :update_vote!(new_value)
                                ^:
  app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:3:in `'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:424:in `block in load_file'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:616:in `new_constants_in'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:423:in `load_file'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require_or_load'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:535:in `get'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3205659148210679757__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.0.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.5) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/louismorin/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

This is my votes_controller.rb file

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :load_post_and_vote
    before_action :update_vote!(new_value)


    def up_vote
        # http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to
        update_vote(:value, 1)
        redirect_to :back
    end

    def down_vote
        update_vote(:value, -1)
        redirect_to :back
    end

    private

    def load_post_and_vote
        # extract into this method the definition of @post and @vote
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @vote = @post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first
    end

    def update_vote!(new_value)
        # Extract vote updating/creating logic here.
    # This method has access to @vote, because of the before_action
    if @vote
            authorize @vote, :update?
            @vote.update_attribute(:value, 1)
        else
            @vote = current_user.votes.build(value: 1, post: @post)
            authorize @vote, :create?
            @vote.save
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: Your `update_vote!` method takes one argument, but you call it with two in your controller code. Since it's being called directly in the applicable controller actions, why not omit this `before_action`?

Comment: See if this link help u [5507026 - before-filter-with-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507026/before-filter-with-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

before_action is given a method name as a symbol. (Or a block, as in the other answer). You can't feed that method an argument like you tried. (Where would that argument come from?)

As before actions, both update_vote and up_vote redirect automatically, meaning they'd never let you hit the action you were trying to call.

Moreover, you're calling update_vote before two actions in which it's explicitly called.

I think you're making a mistake in calling update vote as a before action at all. To fix/avoid the syntax error, I'd remove that line. Update vote is getting called anyway, correctly, with an argument, in your two actions.

If you want behavior that happens immediately before or after post creation, I'd add that in the model.

Comment: Hey Sasha, if I take out the before action for update_vote then I get a no method error `undefined method `update_vote' for #<VotesController:0x007fc14a512e90>`