# After_save with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model

This is my model code:

```
after_create :notify_cards_create
after_destroy :notify_cards_destroy
after_update :notify_cards_update

def notify_cards_update
   WebsocketRails[:home].trigger 'cards', {type: 'update', card: self.as_json({small: true})}
end

def notify_cards_create
    WebsocketRails[:home].trigger 'cards', {type: 'create', card: self.as_json({small: true})}
end

def notify_cards_destroy
    WebsocketRails[:home].trigger 'cards', {type: 'destroy', card: self.as_json({small: true})}
end
```

As you can see it contains many duplications! How can i shorten this code to something like:

```
after_create :notify_cards_create,   'create'
after_destroy :notify_cards_destroy, 'destroy'
after_update :notify_cards_update,   'update'
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507026/before-filter-with-parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would implement it like this:

```
after_create ->(obj) { notify_cards('create') }
after_destroy ->(obj) { notify_cards('update') }
after_update ->(obj) { notify_cards('destroy') }

protected 

def notify_cards(event_type)
  WebsocketRails[:home].trigger 'cards', {type: event_type, card: self.as_json({small: true})}
end
```

The `obj` parameter to the lambda is not mandatory, but you have it available if you want to access the object being created/updated/deleted

Comment: You can use `self` also, it's not like you need the block form, but +1.