# How to catch and redirect rails routes that are valid, but invalid resource id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, path, routes, http-status-code-404

`match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :all if Rails.env.production?` handles things nicely, but it doesn't properly catch cases like this

`/root.com/articles/293` where 293 is an article id that doesn't exist in the database.

In this case, it still redirects to the default 404 page, which on heroku is the ugly "something went wrong" page.

How can I tap into the " valid url, but invalid resource id " url to control its redirect to where I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue-from). It's quite handy when you want to deviate from Rails' default behavior of displaying a 404 page.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

  private

  def record_not_found
    # handle redirect
  end
end
```

Comment: Very nice answer! I didn't know about `rescue_from`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like this is a check you would do in your controller. Something along the lines of:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    if Article.exists?(id)
      #proceed as normal
    else
      #redirect to "Article doesn't exist" page
    end
  end
end
```

You could create a generic method like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

def redirect_if_does_not_exist
  id = params[:id]
  model_name = controller_name.classify.constantize
  unless model_name.exists?(id)
    # handle redirect
  end
end
```

Then you could just call this method in a `before_action` callback on the controllers that you want to check. Like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_does_not_exist
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. I'd like to make a generic method in the application controller so that I don't have to define it in every specific controller. I'm working on trying to incorporate this, perhaps using a parameter, which wouldn't involve interpolating strings to produce the class name. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19113978/2951835 The easy way would be to put a redirect_to within the `set_<resource>` private method in each controller, but doing that seems dirty to me, compared to setting a redirect filter

Comment: actually, doing a redirect in the `set_<resource>` method doesn't trigger the redirect. It still gives the error that the resource wasn't found.

Comment: Something else seems to be triggering a redirect if the resource id is not found BEFORE our custom redirect

Comment: It makes sense to use the default `get_<resource>` to check if a record exists. but doing so triggers the record not found error immediately before exiting the method. This happens when you use the `.find()` method. A way around this is to use `.find_by_id()` instead, which doesn't trigger the error. Then a solution like yours will work. but it still involves modifying each controller's resource-getting method.